# How to work 2 selects dynamics in Ionic 3

Tags: select, ionic3

Could someone teach me how to work with two dynamic selects ? For example, I first select State, then show cities in a second select. How can I make this in Ionic 3?

Comment: You must try a code then if you got error ask here.

Comment: But my friend @amin, I don't know this is it, I know to make one select default, but not 2 selects dynamics, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you `.html`:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>State</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selected_state" (ionChange)="stateSelect(selected_state)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of states" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>City</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selected_city">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of cities" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and in your `.ts`

```
 states = [
{
  name: 'state1'
},
{
  name: 'state2'
}
];
main_cities = [
{
  name: 'city1',
  state: 'state1'
},
{
  name: 'city2',
  state: 'state1'
},
{
  name: 'city3',
  state: 'state2'
},
{
  name: 'city4',
  state: 'state2'
}
];
cities=[];
selected_state;
selected_city;

public stateSelect(selected_state) {
this.cities=[];
for (let city of this.main_cities) {
  if (selected_state == city.state) {
    this.cities.push(city);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: can u have some email address in your profile? @amin

Comment: @n00b I add my gmail.